# How to set the dual color to a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

How to set dual color to an button. Any ideas.

Comment: create Gradient color and set that color in button

Comment: create CAGradientLayer with two colors and inset as sublayer to button

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradient.frame =CGRectMake(0, imageView.frame.size.height-50, CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame), 50);
 gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
 [imageView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```